# How does 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS' work on wp-config?

Tags: wordpress

The text on my wordpress text editor is white on a white background so its invisible for most people..

[image]

I searched it and the solution I found was to add the following code to wp-config.php

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

It worked fine but I couldn't find what it does or why it works.

I only found a question that asks the same thing [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/why-do-i-have-to-add-defineconcatenate_scripts-false) but it didn't get an answer.

**Could someone explain what the code above does and why it works?**

Comment: Do you use any plugin for TinyMCE?

Comment: That's really an odd issue. It seems it's related to some JS - sometimes some scripts doesn't support well to be minified (if it miss some semicolons for example). Does your browser console say anything about it?

Comment: The console doesn't say anything.

Comment: It seems `wp_styles` use `CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS` too in order to know if it should concat the styles. So if you don't have any error message in your console when concat is on, I think it should be some css minifying issue. If you look in your source in admin you'll find some reference to _load-styles.php_ in the head markup. Could you paste those two lines in your question?

Comment: I've also encountered similar issues. 1) My wordpress site returning "**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403**" when I access the theme customization page. 2) Sometimes my browser directly open 403 Forbidden page from server when I do bulk product delete or edit. Issue 1 is solved when i add **define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);** line to wp-config file, but this solution does not resolve my 2nd issue. Issue 1 only occur after I move my wordpress site to new server.
I'm insisted to know what causing this issue, so i disabled the newly added line in my wp-config.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First of all, nice question.

`CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS` is the constant that tells wordpress to, well.. concatenate all of the dependencies into one URL and load it together ( to save http requests I guess ).

As far as I know, it applies only to the Admin area ( back end ).
The result is a url like

```
<script src="http://somewordpress.site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load=jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,hoverIntent,common,jquery-color,wp-ajax-response,wp-lists,jquery-ui-resizable,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,postbox,dashboard,thickbox,plugin-install,media-upload&ver=e0f647a6df61adcc7200ce17a647db7f" type="text/javascript">
```

This is the normal default behavior, and if you have problems with it, it is probably because of some `javascript` conflict in theme or plugin.

Another possible ( albeit less frequent ) is a browser problem due to TinyMCE caching. clear browser cache. ( edit : was true to `Sep.2015` - not verified since but still worth trying )

If you really want to see where it is defined or what is it doing you can [look here](http://wpseek.com/source/wpmu/latest/nav.html?wp-includes/script-loader.php.source.html#l717).

Anyhow, by defining the constant as `false` you are practically forcing  WordPress to load each script on the administration page **individually** rater than **collectively**.
So in that case - If one script fails to load and work correctly, the others can still continue to operate correctly.

This is a recommended setting for `debugging` and local development.
However, in your case, it is a **symptom** of a problem, and not the problem itself. you should isolate the problem and fix it ( probably a plugin like said before )

Comment: Excellent! I'll see what I find.. Thank you!

Comment: Concatenation was an especially valuable technique before dependent scripts could be loaded in parallel, because one script had to wait for the next before downloading. This lag is [becoming less of an issue](https://hackcabin.com/post/managing-async-dependencies-javascript/) in 2017, and depending on how you're loading your scripts concatenation may actually slow down your site. Just so you know.

Comment: A shout from the future. I can't believe I would need this in 2023

Answer (score 8):

To expand upon Obmerk's answer, in my case setting `CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS` to false simply enabled me to see the individual failure in the browser console as it then showed the javascript for tinymce was not loading properly. Then looking at server logs showed that `wp-tinymce.php` was not executing properly. In the end, I needed to fix the permissions of `{sitepath}/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php` so that the security settings of the server I was on would allow it to run.

In my case the server did not allow it to be group-writable so a `chmod 755` took care of it. The actual solution will vary based on your server configuration.

Comment: Interesting... why did you set a PHP script to 755 (which includes the ability of running it directly from a shell) as opposed to 644?

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn just lazy/ignorance on my part.

Comment: Thank you!! I was about to ditch this database and recreate a whole site from scratch. In my case, I saw a Javascript error with a core WP file after migrating from a WordPress installation on Network Solutions who was using Percona instead of MySQL or MariaDB. Scanned for malware with ImunifyAV, cleaned an infected file, then verified the WordPress installation with WP Toolkit and there were about 10 abnormalities. Click "Reinstall WordPress Core" in WP Toolkit and now my plugin updates appeared and no more admin page weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

I 2nd the Tinymice guy, mines turned out to be Tix marking "Classic Editor" in the pre-install options area of the softalicious in WordPress manager .

Seems like you need to do it after, Hope that helps someone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).